# how to create and array of nested controllers for an invoice form ?

Tags: angularjs

I need to create an invoice that the invoice line will be a independent controller due to the complexity of an Invoice Line calculation.
My question is :
How to define an array of InvoiceLine controller and bind them using ng-repeat?

I new to Angular, in knockout i did it like this: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var invoiceTest = angular.module("InvoiceTest", []);

    invoiceTest.controller(
        "InvoiceHead",
        function ($scope) {
            // how to define ? $scope.InvoiceLine = [array of controllers]
            $scope.VAT = 0.17;
            $scope.TotalNoVat = ???; // Neet To Calc the Sum of $scope.InvoiceLine.TotalCost
            $scope.TotalInvluceVAT = function() {
                return ($scope.TotalNoVat * (1+ $scope.VAT)).toFixed(2);
            };
        }
        );

    invoiceTest.controller("InvoiceLine",
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.Description = "";
            $scope.Quantity = 1;
            $scope.Cost = 0;
            $scope.TotalCost = function() {
                return ($scope.Quantity * $scope.Cost).toFixed(2);
            };

            //more complex  calculation and ajax ...
        }
    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Invoice Line Item has a UI component (I would imagine that it does), this sounds like an excellent place to make use of an [AngularJS Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

The directive would contain the necessary logic to display the invoice line item, and it could contain (via its controller) the logic required to calculate the values to display the line item.

If you'd like a bit more separation of your concerns, you could also create an [AngularJS Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) that holds the the logic to calculate the line item values, and [inject the service into your directive's controller.](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers)  This has the benefit of allowing you unit test your calculation logic without needing to involve your display logic.

Here's a real basic example of a service and directive used as described above (with `MainInvoiceController` to hold the `lineItems`):

```
invoiceTest.controller("MainInvoiceController", function($scope){

    // lineItem directive will update Quantity & Cost as user changes
    // changes input values, and recalculate TotalCost any time either
    // Quantity or Cost changes.
    $scope.lineItems = [
        {
            Description : "Item 1",
            Quantity: 2,
            Cost: 2.00,
            TotalCost: 4.00
        },
        {
            Description : "Item 2",
            Quantity: 10,
            Cost: 4.00,
            TotalCost: 40.00
        },
    ]
});

invoiceTest.service("InvoiceCalculationsService", function(){
    // Calculates the total cost of the line item, and
    // updates the TotalCost property of the line item
    this.updateTotalCost = function(lineItemData)
    {
        lineItemData.TotalCost = lineItemData.Quantity * lineItemData.Cost;
    }
});

InvoiceTest.directive("lineItemDisplay", function(InvoiceCalculationsService){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope:{
            // lineItemData is expected to contain the properties:
            // Description
            // Quantity
            // Cost
            // TotalCost
            lineItem:"="
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            this.recalculateTotal = function(){
                InvoiceCalculationsService.updateTotalCost($scope.lineItem);
            }
        },
        template:   'Description: <input data-ng-model="lineItem.Description" />'
                    'Quantity: <input data-ng-model="lineItem.Quantity" data-ng-change="recalculateTotal()" />' +
                    'Cost: <input data-ng-model="lineItem.Cost" data-ng-change="recalculateTotal()" />' + 
                    'Total: <span>{{lineItem.TotalCost}}</span>'
    }
});
```

And here's the directive in use, with `ng-repeat':

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainInvoiceController">
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems">
        <line-item-display data-line-item="lineItem"></line-item-display>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```